# Fluent NHibernate unable to change a lookup record?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Ok, I'm new to NHibernate so maybe someone here can explain this. I have 3 tables/entities:

- Applications
- Roles
- ApplicationRoles

As it sounds, ApplicationRoles is a lookup table that has foreign keys to Applications and Roles, and some other fields like IsActive.

Now in the code, ApplicationRole has a reference to both parents, Application and Role. And the Application object has a List so it can reference the child ApplicationRole objects. Role does not, but I tried adding it and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to load an ApplicationRole object directly, manipulate it, and save it again. I can load the object, either by it's own PK, or both FKs, and I can change it's IsActive field, but when I save it back to the database I get an error about 'collection not processed with flush' on the Application object and it's other child collections.

I think this may be due to lazy loading as it does not happen if I use the debugger and inspect the object's Application parent reference, the save goes through fine. But if I don't I get the above error.

If I load the Application object and manipulate it's child ApplicationRole object, and save the Application itself, it works, but I feel that I shouldn't have to do that.

EDIT: clarified the data relationships

Answer (score 1):

you can ditch the class ApplicationRole completly

```
Application
{
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; private set; }
}

// in ApplicationMap
HasManyToMany(a => a.Roles)
    .Table("ApplicationRole")
    .ParentKeyColumn("application_id")
    .ChildKeyColumn("role_id")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteorphan();
```

Comment: This is good, but unfortunately I do have 1 or 2 bit fields on the linking record, so it's not purely a lookup table. It has a field IsDefault and some other such.

Comment: oh, this is important info which should be in the question. I'll try answering again when i have time